# jQuery dataTable crashed only in PROD

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

My dataTable crashed, that is the search box suddenly disappeared and the rows got cut. It did not happen in the local or QA environment only in production for almost 120 rows to be displayed. here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>title...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#table").dataTable( {
                    "bStateSave": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .newline{
                margin : 0px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="table.jsp">
           //geting some input from the user
        </form>

       <fieldset style="margin-top: 50px;">
            <legend>legend</legend>
            <table class="tbl" id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>th1</th>
                        <th>th2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    //filling the table out
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

-Isn't jquery a client-side script? then why did it crash only in one environment?
-Can I modify the code to prevent that in future?

I am completely a beginner in jquery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check if there is any relevant error on the browser console. It seems you're failing to get any of the js files but with error description we'll be able to help better.

Comment: You have little chance to get meaningful answers with the amount of detail you have provided. In this case, you would need to post complete details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check if can find tips on console (Firebug or Chrome Inspector[F12 key]). Yes, that's client code, shouldn't be affected by server-side configuration, so: 1. check if jquery, jquery.datatables and any other asset are equal. 2. Retrieve JQuery from a CDN. 3. Make sure you use same machine/browser.